# Same webscrape code works on one page, not another using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I built a simple scrape to get a data frame with NFL draft results for 2020. I intent to use this code to map several years of results but for some reason, when I change the code for a single page scrape for any other year than 2020, I get the error at the bottom.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(curl)
```

This scrape for 2020 works flawlesslessy, although the col names are in row 1 which isn't a big deal to me as I can deal with this later (mentioning though in case this might have to do with the problem):

```
x <- "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/draft.htm"
df <- read_html(curl(x, handle = curl::new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))) %>% 
        html_nodes("table") %>% 
        html_table() %>%
        as.data.frame()
```

below the url is changed from 2020 to 2019 which is an active page with a table of the same format. For some reason, the same call as above does not work:

```
x <- "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019/draft.htm"
df <- read_html(curl(x, handle = curl::new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))) %>% 
        html_nodes("table") %>% 
        html_table() %>%
        as.data.frame()

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 261, 2
```

Comment: Can't speak for R, but it works fine for me with Python. Are you running a loop that is iterating through each year/season?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tables at the url provided. There is the core draft (table 1, `id = "drafts"`) and the supplemental draft (table 2, `id = "drafts_supp"`).

The `as.data.frame()` call fails because it is trying to combine the two tables but they have differing columns in both name and number. You can direct `rvest` to read just the specific table you are interested in by providing the `html_node()` with either the `xpath` or the `selector`. You can find the `xpath` or `selector` by inspecting the specific table you are interested in, right-click > inspect on Chrome/Mozilla. Note that for selector to use id you'll need to use `#drafts` not just `drafts` and for xpath you typically have to wrap the text in single quotes.

- This works: `html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="drafts"]')`
- This doesn't because of the double quotes: `html_node(xpath = "//*[@id="drafts"]")`

Note that I believe the `html_nodes("table")` used in your example is unnecessary, as `html_table()` already selects only tables.

```
x <- "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019/draft.htm"

raw_html <- read_html(x)

# use xpath
raw_html %>% 
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="drafts"]') %>%
  html_table()

# use selector
raw_html %>% 
  html_node("#drafts") %>% 
  html_table()
```